# Alexa activates intent even though the slot.value does not exist in the JSON file

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, jovo-framework

So I have this intent:

```js
    'PlayRadioIntent': function(channel) {
    
                
               
                this.setSessionAttribute('RadioName', channel);
                this.followUpState('PlayConfirmationState')
                .ask('Do you want me to play your stupid ' + channel.value);
                

            },
```

Which is activated if the user says : I want to listen to *slot:radio_name*.
When I test it with:
I want to listen to eaaehae.
Alexa replies with:
*There was a problem with the requested skill's response.*
Which makes perfect sense since eaaehar does not exist in the radios database that I have provided*

---

The problem is that when I test it with:
I want to listen to eaaehae radio.
Alexa replies with:
*Do you want me to play your stupid eaaehae radio.*
This doesn't make any sense since eaaehae radio does not exist in the radios  database that I have provided
Does anyone know what might be causing this issue. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There was a problem with the requested skill's response. Which makes
>   perfect sense since eaaehar does not exist in the radios database that
>   I have provided*

Whenever Alexa respond back with **"There was a problem with the requested skill's response"** It only means that your code was unable to provide a valid response. Be it an error message or an expected response you are supposed to send back only a valid response.

In your case, you need to validate the slot-values you receive in radio_name slot with the expected values from you database and send back a valid response.